# Expand cell array iteratively

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have two cell arrays of different sizes and want to compare the cells in the first column of `cellarray1` with the cells of the first column of `cellarray2`. If two cells are equal, take the information in the succeeding columns in that row in `cellarray2` [could be a string, an int], and put it in `cellarray1`. What I need really is to know how to expand `cellarray1` this flexibly.

The first columns of the two arrays are strings, `Po001, Po002` etc... 
`Cellarray1` will have two copies of each string, `Po001, Po001, Po002, Po002` etc.
It's just that, I need to match the two arrays, if they match, I add the information in the other columns of `cellarray2` which should be general, 
that is, the second column contains strings with two values e.g. `Object1, Object2`. The third column contains a `1` or `2`. It just that I don't know how to expand rows of cellarrays with new cells, which after a whole for loop results in `N` new columns in cellarray1.

```
for ii = 1:length(cellarray2(:,1))
     for jj = 1:length(cellarray1(:,1))
         if strcmp(cellarray2{ii,1}, cellarray1{jj,1})
            % This seems to give the results I want but I 
            % dont know how to update the original cellarray1 
            % with this new row 
            [cellarray1(ii,1:end), cellarray2(jj,1:end)]
         end
     end
end
```

If this can be done it would be really good. Ideally, I would like to input the information from `cellarray2`, just after the first column of `cellarray1`. Like, create one column in `cellarray1`, for each column of `cellarray2`, and then input that information in `cellarray1` if of course the comparison is `true`.

Best regards,
Granit

Comment: is everything in cellarray2 for sure in cellarray1?

Comment: Could you give an example of what (parts) of the cellarray1 and cellarray2 look like? And, also if possible, an example of how the ouput would look like.

Comment: Thanx for your engagement. I've added the information you asked for. As for the output, it will just be a cellarray, a merging of cellarray1 and cellarray2, with the rows of cellarray2 merged with the correct row of cellarray1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a vector of indexes to indicate which rows from `cellarray1(:,1)` match with `cellarray2(:,1)` using `cellfun` , `find` and `strcmp`

```
% Find the first location of match from cellarray1 in cellarray2
locIdx = cellfun(@(x)find(strcmp(x,cellarray2(:,1)),1),cellarray1(:,1));
```

Now you can copy columns from `cellarray2` to `cellarray1` like:

```
cellarray1(:,2:end) = cellarray2(locIdx,2:end);  
% I used 2:end assuming you want to copy only the non key columns
```

Or if you want to append the columns into `cellarray1`:

```
width2 = size(cellarray2,2);
cellarray1(:,end+1:end+width2-1) = cellarray2(locIdx,2:end);
```

Comment: Excellent. Using cellarray1(:,2:end) = cellarray2(locIdx,2:end) led to a dimension mismatch. But the last stuff you wrote did the job (I seem not to be able to upvote)!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Some Guy overrides the values from cellarray1 with the values from cellarray2. i feel like you were looking for a solution where you would add them at the end of the array so in case i was right here would be a solution:

```
%please always add data examples to your posts
cellarray1={'A' 1;'B' 2;'C' 3;'D' 4;'E' 5};
cellarray2={'A' 'X'; 'D' 'Y';'E' 'Z'};

%there is no width() so you have to do it like this or with size()
width1=length(cellarray1(1,:));
width2=length(cellarray2(1,:));

for ii = 1:length(cellarray2(:,1))
     for jj = 1:length(cellarray1(:,1))
         %you got the ii and jj mixed up here
         if strcmp(cellarray2{ii,1}, cellarray1{jj,1})
           %either you overwrite everything with this 
           %cellarray1(ii,1:width1+width2-1) = [cellarray1(ii,:) cellarray2(jj,2:end)];
           %or you just add them at the end on cellarray1 with this
           cellarray1(jj,width1+1:width1+width2-1) = cellarray2(ii,2:end);
         end
     end
end
```

please note that when the if case is true for the first time cellarray1 will change its size from (X,width1) to (X,width1+width2-1).
Also i feel like performance is not an issue here, but if this cellarray1 and cellarray2 are really big or this function should be called a lot, you should vectorize both for loops.

Comment: I misunderstood the question in the beginning and have updated my answer accordingly, if appending vs overwriting is a concern I have added that as well. Please upvote if you think mine is a good way to get this done.

Comment: nice! in that case you should take his solution, as that would be the vectorization i mentioned in the end of mine

Comment: @Granit you should know though that `cellfun` is not vectorization, it's just a fancy loop (but can be slower than a simple `for`). Try to benchmark (using `timeit`) the solutions to see what is really faster.

Comment: I havent really looked into vectorization. I naturally think in for loops. But will definitely look it. And thanx @EBH for further information.

Comment: The time for @SomeGuy 's solution is 0.0161 while with the for loop solution given by Finn is 0.0487. Its not a huge dataset.

Comment: @Granit Well, that's great, and it's mostly because Finn used nested loop, while @SomeGuy used only one `cellfun`.

Comment: also he uses the loop only to find the indices, but the assining is vectorized. i believe you could vectorize the `strcmp` part too (with `ismember` or something), but it seems the dataset does not require further optimization